# How to make a python module that compiles C code?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am trying to make a python module that installs via Pip.  Specifically, I am trying to package the [omniORBpy python module version 3.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/omniorb/files/omniORBpy/omniORBpy%203.0/) .  Currently to install this package I would run ./configure , make, make install.  Pretty typical.  So how do I make a pip package that does that for me?  I see ext_modules directive in setup.py, is that what I need?